# UI Challenge - how to draw "connectors" between elements?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, view, prototypejs

Take a look at my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/12/

What I want to do is create a connector from the second tr to all the tr's below except for the last one.  Here's a mockup:

[image]

How would I accomplish this via a combo of CSS/HTML/Prototype/Rails?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but could you use nested lists for this, instead of a table?  I suspect nested lists would be much easier to work with, as they can capture the hierarchy inherent in your setup, where tables can't.

Comment: You can also use Unicode for characters like that: http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Take a look at my suggestion for a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/13/

Answer (score 0):

I am truly a fan of jimmy's answer, but i have tried to do this without the use of images.
I know its not as good as it can be with the use of images, but probably it can be improved upon to actually get it working without images.

Here's what i have done: http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/15/